# Replace drainage assembly in concrete sink

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I have a really old (over 50 years) concrete sink, but the metal part of the drain underneath is completely rotten through and need to replace it

[image: Underneath sink]

The drainage pipe is all 1.5 inches.

The white painted pipe on the left of the picture is used as a washing machine drainage.

I'm guessing I would need to cut all the pipes that go to the T fitting, but what would be the best way to remove the top drainage assembly?

[image: Top drainage 1]
[image: Top drainage 2]

Comment: Just cut the white pipe (painted?) and the trap assembly should pull off the sink tailpiece. With a coupling (make the cut to leave enough pipe that you can use one) it might even be re-usable. Or glue in a union to make this more serviceable in the future.

Comment: @Ecnerwal The white pipe actually goes up. It is used for a washing machine drainage. Apart from the screw to the top assembly, which is my main problem where all the rust is, everything else is glued on. Including going to the drainage to the wall in the back wall.